# Run Windows Phone 8.1 RT app under lockscreen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

How can I make my Windows Phone 8.1 app continue to run under the lockscreen like I can in Windows Phone 8 using the following code:

```
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
        PhoneApplicationFrame rootFrame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
        if (rootFrame != null)
        {
            rootFrame.Obscured += new EventHandler<ObscuredEventArgs>(rootFrame_Obscured);
            rootFrame.Unobscured += new EventHandler(rootFrame_Unobscured);
        }
```

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 runtime (store) app as in not the Silverlight type one so for a start it seems that PhoneApplicationService is not part of this API so the above code will not work. Does anyone have an idea what the recommended way of doing this in Windows Phone 8.1 is?

PS.
If this is not possible as I am beginning to dread is the case, what are my alternative options?

Comment: I do not believe this is currently supported in XAML apps

Comment: @ShawnKendrot I hoped this was not the case

Comment: Are you trying to build a Universal App or a regular Windows Phone 8.1 only app?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

When building RT Windows Phone 8.1 apps, `PhoneApplicationService` is no longer available (only available for Silverlight Windows Phone 8.1 apps).

At this point, it doesn't look like there is a direct replacement but there are workarounds being performed using the [`DisplayRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.system.display.displayrequest.aspx) class.

**OLD**

If you double check the documentation for [`PhoneApplicationService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice), you'll notice that it is still supported in Windows Phone 8.1.

I'm guessing that you're building a Universal App and that you're trying to put this code into part of the Shared Project that is used by both the Windows 8.1 and the Windows Phone 8.1 project.

In that case, you'll need to use the supported Preprocessor directives to specify platform specific sections of your code:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP

PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = 
    IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
// etc.

#endif
```

You can read more about how to share different bits of code in Universal Applications at:

[How to share code among different Universal Windows apps](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/how-to-share-code-among-different-universal-windows-apps/) (which discusses the above method towards the bottom of the article)

Comment: I am actually not working on a shared part, I am working directly in the WP8.1 part but Visual Studio cannot find my reference to PhoneApplicationService

Comment: @Gerhman - Ok. Then your question confuses me. There is no Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime (Store App). You're either writing a Windows 8.1 RT (Store) App OR a Windows Phone 8.1 application. There's a huge difference in what is available to you.

Comment: I thought so too but it seems there is a distinction, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn632732.aspx indicates there are different libraries for RT and Silverlight Apps

Comment: The difference being it seems that RT apps use basically the same runtime as those for Win8 whereas Silverlight apps use WP specific ones

Comment: Justin, you can build a Windows Phone 8.1 app using **either** Silverlight or the Runtime, but not both. While the documentation says it is supported in 8.1, it is only supported in Silverlight 8.1. A "Universal App" is just a Runtime based app.

Comment: I am shocked at this, why would they even do this :( Where I can file complaints to Microsoft. No wonder most developers stay away :(